# jQuery SmoothDivScroll - endlessloop works with images but not text in a list

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

Here is the default SmoothDivScroll demo but with endlessloopright, everything works fine:

http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/smoothdivscroll/jQuery%20Smooth%20Div%20Scroll%20by%20Thomas%20Kahn%20-%20smooth%20content%20scrolling%20using%20jQuery.html

Here all ive done is replace the images with text in a list. It does scroll but it doesn't loop:

http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/smoothdivscroll/LIST%20-%20jQuery%20Smooth%20Div%20Scroll%20by%20Thomas%20Kahn%20-%20smooth%20content%20scrolling%20using%20jQuery%20copy.html
Anyone have an idea why this is happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I put the text in divs, not in a list.